# Render an R Markdown file (.Rmd) from its GitHub URL

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to get R to render an R Markdown file (.Rmd) from its GitHub raw URL, but I haven't found a way to make it work.

Here's a simple reproducible example, using a random, publicly-hosted .Rmd file on GitHub:

```
library(rmarkdown)

render("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FukamiLab/BIO202/master/00-computer-setup.Rmd")
```

Instead of rendering the document as an HTML file in my working directory, I get the following error message:

```
Error in abs_path(input) : 
The file 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FukamiLab/BIO202/master/00-computer-setup.Rmd' does not exist.
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
path[1]="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FukamiLab/BIO202/master/00-computer-setup.Rmd": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Hopefully there's a solution to this, thanks in advance!

Comment: `render` must work with local files. Download it first (optionally into a temporary file), then render and delete the `.Rmd` file if you want.

Comment: For example, `tf <- tempfile(); download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FukamiLab/BIO202/master/00-computer-setup.Rmd", tf); rmarkdown::render(tf)`, but unfortunately this fails here because this file references `.png` files in the repo. So ... clone or download all portions manually.

Comment: pea, it seems to me that if you're taking that class and need to render that document, you would need the other documents in the repo at some point soon (during the semester?). In that case, it seems prudent to just clone the whole repo with `git clone https://github.com/FukamiLab/BIO202.git` and work with the files locally.

Comment: r2evans, thanks a lot for the help. Regarding your last comment, the URL I included in my question was chosen only because it's a public .Rmd file hosted on GitHub. I have nothing to do with that repo nor am I a student in that class. My reason for wanting to refer to an online .rmd file within `render()` is that I have multiple apps using the same R Markdown report and I want to make sure they're all using the same version of the file.

Comment: Okay, great clarification, thank you. Does your scenario also include multiple sub-components like images or child documents?

Comment: no, nothing of the sort

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like my second comment (using `tf <- tempfile(); ...`) should work for you.